# jQuery: Stop onclick looping on appended link

Tags: jquery

How to stop this click from looping?

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
   var elements = $('.elements'),
       elcounts = $(this).closest('ul').attr('data-counter'), // default = 0
       elupdate = Number(elcounts)+1, // increase count by 1
       eldata = $(this).attr('data-element');
   elements.append('<div><a href="#">x</a>'+eldata+'</div>');
   $(this).closest('ul').attr('data-counter',elupdate);

   elements.on('click','a',function(){
      var ulId = $(this).attr('data-ulsource'),
          ulelement = $('ul#'+ulId),
          countsCurrent = ulelement.attr('data-counter'), // get current counters
          countsUpdate = Number(countsCurrent)-1; // decrease count by 1
      ulelement.attr('data-counter',countsUpdate);
      $(this).parent().remove();
      alert(countsUpdate); // testing this
      return false;
   });
}
```

Click li appears like this:

```
[x] Data1, [x] Data2, [x] Data3 etc.
```

Clicking appended a [x] to remove, always return looping counter as how many div there.
If I have added/click li 3 times, then when I click one of the [x], alert always show 3 times, and counters value decreased randomly or something to 2,0,-1 etc.
How to solve this? Or did I miss something here?

Comment: Everytime you click `li` you bind a click event to `a`. Don't bind events inside another.

Comment: You need to move `elements.on('click','a',function(){` event handler outside.

Comment: @Satpal It's not working when I move outside, alert won't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move event delegation outside of `li` click event handler. Everytime you click `li` you bind a click event to `a` hence looping.

*Use*

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    var elements = $('.elements'),
        elcounts = $(this).closest('ul').attr('data-counter'), // default = 0
        elupdate = Number(elcounts) + 1, // increase count by 1
        eldata = $(this).attr('data-element');
    elements.append('<div><a href="#">x</a>' + eldata + '</div>');
    $(this).closest('ul').attr('data-counter', elupdate);
});
$('.elements').on('click', 'a', function() {
    var ulId = $(this).attr('data-ulsource'),
        ulelement = $('ul#' + ulId),
        countsCurrent = ulelement.attr('data-counter'), // get current counters
        countsUpdate = Number(countsCurrent) - 1;
    //decrease count by 1
    ulelement.attr('data-counter', countsUpdate);
    $(this).parent().remove();
    alert(countsUpdate); // testing this
    return false;
});
```

Also, I would recommend you to use [**.data()**](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of `.attr()` like

```
var countsUpdate = ulelement.data('counter');
ulelement.data('counter', countsUpdate);
```

Comment: Ahh, it's working now! I missed one line to fix after moving elements outside event handler. Thanks a lot!!! =)